# What does "boot-bashing" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In his book **Turkey: A Short History** [Norman Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Stone) writes:

> Madrid and Ankara are both artificial capitals, without economic
> activity between penpushing and boot-bashing...

I can't find many plausible meanings for "boot-bashing". There are some references to the term in reference to hiking, and Australians seem to use it to mean kicking someone in a fight. Neither seems appropriate here.

I suppose it could be referring to parades with a military component, or soldiers marching about in drills, but that does not seem to be a common usage.

Comment: My best guess is that this means "boot" as in "trunk of a car," thus referring to robbing vehicles. This sense of the word is only used in British English, though, so I defer to someone who actually knows BrE.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's a good suggestion. Oxford Dictionary of Slang says "xx bashing" is 1940s British services' slang for any arduous task. Personally, as a Canadian, I'd never heard the term "square bashing".

Comment: My first thought was "cobbling" - shoe repair.

Comment: Turkey has one of the largest [armed forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Armed_Forces) in Europe and in NATO, and a lot is based in Ankara (even the [navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Naval_Forces)!). There are [major bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankara_G%C3%BCvercinlik_Army_Air_Base) [in the area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimesgut_Air_Base). So it seems reasonable to characterise Ankara as a city with a lot of military personnel. Even if it might be a slightly mixed-up metaphor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think OP's supposition is probably right and that this is a reference to soldiers on parade.  I gloss it as a variation on *square-bashing* which my dictionary (Chambers 11th edn) defines as

> n (*milit sl*) parade ground drill

It's an elliptical reference to artificial capitals being stuffed full of soldiers in their best parade-ground uniforms marching about bashing their boots against the tarmacadam. By contrast *natural capitals* (eg London, Paris) are filled with much else besides pen-pushers and boot-bashers.

That would seem to fit with the idea expressed by *penpushing* - such capitals are populated by bureaucrats and soldiers (of the kind known as *chocolate soldiers*), all suckers on the tits of the public purse and all of questionable value to the taxpayer.

I have no citations for this interpretation of *boot-bashing*, I searched the usual places and found nothing authoritative, not even semi-authorative.  This is English under construction, an author stretching it and a native speaker figuring out the direction of travel.

Comment: +1 Yes. "The only activity in these capitals is bureaucracy and military" i.e. both government activities.

Comment: As another data point, I queried a friend who was an officer in the  South African military and he responded without the slightest prompting that "It's drill on a square" (and went on to complain about the practice).

Answer (score 2):

Feasibly the author had encountered it before, but most likely from his perspective it was just his own "nonce-coinage" based on merging these US and UK idiomatic usages...

> **boot camp** (US)  [<sup>Cambridge</sup>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boot-camp)
> a place for training soldiers

> **spud bashing**<sup>1</sup> (UK) [<sup>Wiktionary</sup>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spud_bashing)
> the chore of peeling potatoes, especially when given as a punishment.

Hence in the cited context ***boot-bashing*** means mindless / low-grade ***physical*** labour, as opposed to ***pen-pushing,*** which is mindless ***clerical*** labour.

---

<sup>1</sup> Also [square-bashing](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100525955;jsessionid=AAE46831E0BBBDD1618FCE94E1471CE8) (military drill performed repeatedly on a barrack square).
Arguably this is a more relevant sense, since the author clearly wants to imply ***non-productive*** work - but at least spud-bashing puts food on the table for squaddies!

Comment: An excellent answer, however I can select only one, so please accept my upvote and thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't need the points, obviously! But I'm still convinced ***boot*** here alludes to the US ***boot camp*** usage (***not*** directly to UK "square-bashing"). Reason being BrE has *many* "XXX-bashing" idioms, but all except "spud-" and "square-" relate to violence (paki-bashing, queer-bashing, etc.), not monotony. After using NGrams to establish that the most common word before "square-bashing" is in fact ***of***, I checked Google Books, where the only occurrence of ***of boot-bashing*** is AmE [The Immortals.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+boot+bashing%22)

Answer (score -2):

Your link to the Wikipedia article on Norman Stone may offer a clue:
"During this period he spent three months imprisoned in Bratislava, having been caught trying to **smuggle a Hungarian dissident in his car boot** across the Iron Curtain at the Czech–Austrian border."

Maybe he moved some things in Turkey and Spain, too. The combination of "pen-pushing" and "boot-bashing", for a writer, would seem to refer to his personal economic activities, so maybe "boot-bashing" is smuggling.

Comment: That seems to be a very tenuous link and would have been better as a comment.